# How to find same values in two Lists of objetcs scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

So I need to find in two different size arrays same id values and then create another array including id, rdl values from the first array, and amount value from the second array

This is the one I have tried, and I know it doesn't works, because I take elements in course, and I have no idea how to do it

```
case class LenderTotalBalanceData(lenderId: String, direction: String, amount: BigDecimal)
case class LenderCashOutBody(lenderId: String, amount: BigDecimal, rdlAcc: String)

val sortedCashOutData = Seq(LenderCashOutData("9a268e12-c7fd-37dc-9875-a705296f707c","testRdlAcc"))
val sortedBalanceData = Seq(LenderTotalBalanceData("20268e12-c7fd-37dc-9875-a705296f707c","source", 0.0),LenderTotalBalanceData("9a268e12-c7fd-37dc-9875-a705296f707c","source", 0.0))

val seqOfDto = sortedCashOutData.zip(sortedBalanceData).map {
  case (x, y) =>
    if (x.lenderId == y.lenderId)
      LenderCashOutBody(
        x.lenderId,
        y.amount,
        x.rdl
      )
}
```

So as a result i want `LenderCashOutBody("9a268e12-c7fd-37dc-9875-a705296f707c", 0.0, "testRdlAcc")`

Answer (score 3):

Method `zip` connects sequences by index and you need to find value with matching *id* in another array.

I guess the simplest solution to match both arrays by id would be to use `find`:

```
case class LenderTotalBalanceData(lenderId: String, direction: String, amount: BigDecimal)
case class LenderCashOutBody(lenderId: String, amount: BigDecimal, rdlAcc: String)
case class LenderCashOutData(lenderId: String, rdl: String)

val sortedCashOutData = Seq(LenderCashOutData("9a268e12-c7fd-37dc-9875-a705296f707c","testRdlAcc"))
val sortedBalanceData = Seq(LenderTotalBalanceData("20268e12-c7fd-37dc-9875-a705296f707c","source", 0.0),LenderTotalBalanceData("9a268e12-c7fd-37dc-9875-a705296f707c","source", 0.0))

val seqOfDto = sortedCashOutData.flatMap {
  case LenderCashOutData(lenderId, rdl) => sortedBalanceData
   .find(_.lenderId == lenderId)
   .map {
     case LenderTotalBalanceData(_, _, amount) => {
       LenderCashOutBody(
         lenderId,
         amount,
         rdl
       )
     }
  }
}
```

You may also write it with `for-comprehension`, which is arguably more readable (but it won't stop nested searching after finding first matching value):

```
val seqOfDto = for {
  LenderCashOutData(lenderId, rdl) <- sortedCashOutData
  LenderTotalBalanceData(tbLenderId, _, amount) <- sortedBalanceData if tbLenderId == lenderId
} yield LenderCashOutBody(
  lenderId,
  amount,
  rdl
)
```

If your sequences are very big, probably you should consider using `Map` with *id* as a key to speed-up lookups.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative using `flatMap` and `collect`:

```
val seqOfDto = sortedCashOutData.flatMap{ case LenderCashOutData(lenderId, rdl) =>
  sortedBalanceData.collect{
    case LenderTotalBalanceData(id, _, amt) if id == lenderId =>
      LenderCashOutBody(id, amt, rdl)
  }
}
```

Consider replacing [`collect`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/Seq.html#collect[B](pf:PartialFunction[A,B]):Seq[B]) with [`collectFirst`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/Seq.html#collectFirst[B](pf:PartialFunction[A,B]):Option[B]) if only the first matched is wanted or if `lenderId` is unique in `sortedBalanceData`.